# WTForms with Material Design Lite

Tags: wtforms, flask-wtforms, material-design-lite

I'm trying to use mdl and flask-wtf to render a simple form.
According to the [documentation](http://www.getmdl.io/components/index.html#textfields-section) i have to add the mdl classes to the form.

```
5. Add one or more MDL classes, separated by spaces, to the div container, text field, field label, and error message using the class attribute.

<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
  <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="user" pattern="[A-Z,a-z, ]*">
  <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="user">User name</label>
  <span class="mdl-textfield__error">Letters and spaces only</span>
</div>
```

So i'm using this in my templates:

```
<form method="POST">
  {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
  <div class=mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfiedl--floating-label">
    {{ form.email.label }}
    {{ form.email(class="mdl-textfield__input") }}
  </div>
</form>
```

This doesn't fully work because i need to add the *mdl-textfield__label* class to the label.

Is there a way to do this using wtforms or do i have to ignore the {{ form.email.label }} part and just make the label myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest writing your own template macro. That way you could get your forms looking exactly as you want, and all your forms will look the same throughout your site.

Take a look here: http://bear-z.com/python/render-bootstrap-3-forms-with-wtforms-and-jinja/